# A question about continuous curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuous function such that 
$$f(a)=(0,0),\ f(b)=(0,1).$$
Is it true that there must exist $t_1,t_2\in [a,b]$ such that
$\displaystyle f(t_1)-f(t_2)=(0,\frac{1}{2})?$

If not, please give a counterexample.

Comment: The obvious generalization to $n \geq 3$ is false. Consider the case $n = 3$: there are paths from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(0, 0, 1)$ such that no two points are $(0, 0, 1/2)$ apart. Take for, example, $[a, b] = (0, 1)$; then $f(t) = (\cos (2\pi t) - 1, \sin (2 \pi t), t)$ sketches out one revolution of a helix and has no points with the same $x$ and $y$ coordinates except for the endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

More of a comment, the particular case $f(t) = (f_1(t), t)$, the graph of a function, is relevant, and somehow well known. In this case, if $f_1(0)=f_1(1)$, there exists $t$, $t+\frac{1}{2}\in [0,1]$ so that 
$f_1(t) = f_1(t+\frac{1}{2})$. The proof should be clear. It should work with $\frac{1}{n}$ -but not with other distances! ( there are counter examples).So for those  proofs that work for any $\delta >0$, they shouldn't.

${Added:}$ Here is a [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00871v1.pdf) to an article with more  relevant references on "horizontal chords in graphs".

$\bf{Added:}$ Here is an example of a function $f(t) = (f_1(t), t)$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(0) = (0,0)$, $f(1)= (0,1)$, so that there does not exist on this curve a vertical chord or length $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Take $f_1(t) = \sin(8 t) - t \sin 8$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a counterexample?

Comment: @Wen: added a link

Comment: @Wen : added a counterexample

Comment: Your added counterexample is very interesting. It raises the question which values of $\alpha\in[0,1]$ *must* appear as the length of a vertical chord. I initialy thought all of $[0,1]$, but this example shows otherwise.

Comment: An easier counterexample would be $f(t)=(\sin(2\pi t),t)$ which has no vertical chord of any length $\alpha\in(1/2,1)$. Still no idea how to avoid chord lengths in $(0,1/2]$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is true. I'll give a detailed proof based on homotopy invariance of winding number of closed paths in $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,1/2)$. (There's nothing special about $(0,1/2)$ in the theory of winding numbers, of course, but I'll stick with that point since its the relevant center of winding numbers for this problem).

**Winding number theory.** I'll use the notation $W(\gamma)$ for the winding number around $(0,1/2)$ of any closed path 
$$\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}
$$
Just to review the definition of winding number around $(0,1/2)$, one uses polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ centered at $(0,1/2)$, given by 
$$(x,y) = (0,1/2) + (r \cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))
$$
For any path $W : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$ one defines its winding number around $(0,1/2)$ to be
$$W(\gamma) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\gamma d\theta \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
One can also use covering space theory, which for computations in this problem is easier to use. The universal covering space of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$ is identified (using polar coordinates) with the upper half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{(\theta,r) \mid \theta \in \mathbb{R}, r > 0\}$ using the covering map $g : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$ given by the formula
$$g(r,\theta) = (0,1/2) + (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta))
$$
Then one chooses any lift $\tilde\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{H}$ with coordinate functions $r \circ \tilde\gamma : [0,1] \to (0,\infty)$ and $\theta \circ \tilde\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and then
$$W(\gamma) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\bigl(\theta\circ\tilde\gamma(1) - \theta\circ\tilde\gamma(0)\bigr)
$$
This number is well-defined independent of the choice of the lift $\tilde\gamma$.

In the special case that $\gamma$ is a closed path in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$, the number $W(\gamma)$ is always an integer, and invariant under homotopy of closed paths in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$.

The formula for $W(\gamma)$ is defined for any path in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,1/2)\}$, not just for closed paths, and there's a few useful little facts which can be easily proved using the covering space definition:

> **Fact 1**: If $(0,1/2)$ is the midpoint of the segment $\overline{\gamma(0),\gamma(1)}$ then $W(\gamma)$ is a half integer, $$W(\gamma) = n + \frac{1}{2} \quad\text{for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$}$$

--

> **Fact 2**: Letting $R : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ denote any rigid rotation of the plane around $(0,1/2)$, and letting $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$ be any path, we have $$W(R \circ \gamma) = W(\gamma)$$

--

> **Fact 3**: $W$ is additive under concatenation. That is, for any concatenation of paths $\gamma = \gamma_1 * \gamma_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2 - (0,1/2)$ we have $$W(\gamma)=W(\gamma_1)+W(\gamma_2)$$

**Working with the path $f$.** Allow me to reparameterize the path $f$ to have domain $[0,1]$, so
$$f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2
$$
such that $f(0)=(0,0)$ and $f(1)=(0,1)$.

Denote
$$T = \{(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \mid x \le y\}
$$
which is just the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$ together with the inside of that triangle. Thus $T$ is homeomorphic to the 2-disc $D^2$, by a homeomorphism that takes the boundary triangle $\partial T$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$.

Define $F : T \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by the formula
$$F(x,y) = f(y)-f(x)
$$
The goal is to prove that the point $(0,1/2)$ is in the image of $F$.

**Case 1:** If there exists $(x,y) \in \partial T$ such that $F(x,y)=(0,1/2)$ then we're done.

**Case 2:** Suppose that $F(x,y) \ne (0,1/2)$ for each $(x,y) \in \partial T$. It follows that $F \mid \partial T$ is a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,1/2)\}$.

> Claim: The winding number of $F \mid \partial T$ around $\{(0,1/2)\}$ is nonzero: $$W(F \mid \partial T) \ne 0$$

Once this claim is proved, then by applying homotopy invariance of winding number it follows that $F \mid \partial T$ is not homotopic in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,1/2)\}$ to a constant curve. But $F \mid \partial T$ **is** homotopic to a constant curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$: the function $F : T \to \mathbb{R}^2$ may be regarded as such a homotopy, considering that the topological pairs $(T,\partial T)$ and $(D^2,S^1)$ are homeomorphic. Therefore, the image of $F$ must contain $(0,1/2)$.

**Proving the claim.** Let me write $\partial T$ as a closed path $\tau$ which is a concatenation of its three sides $\tau = \tau_v * \tau_h * \tau_d$ where:

- $\tau_v$ is the vertical side going upwards, $\tau_v(t)=(0,t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.
- $\tau_h$ is the horizontal side going rightwards, $\tau_h(t)=(t,1)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.
- $\tau_d$ is the diagonal side going down and to the left $\tau_d(t)=(1-t,1-t)$  for $t \in [0,1]$.

The path $F | \partial T$ can be written as a concatenation of three paths:
$$F | \partial T = (F \circ \tau_v) * (F \circ \tau_h) * (F \circ \tau_d)
$$
and so, by Fact 3, we have
$$W(F | \partial T) = W(F \circ \tau_v) + W(F \circ \tau_h) + W(F \circ \tau_d)
$$
and we have to show this sum is nonzero.

Notice that $F$ is constant on $\tau_d$, namely $F(\tau_d(t))=(0,0)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. It follows that $W(F \circ \tau_d)=0$, so we just have to show that the sum
$$W(F \circ \tau_v) + W(F \circ \tau_h)
$$
is not zero.

Now let's examine those two paths separately:
\begin{align*}
F(\tau_v(t)) &= F(0,t) = f(t)-f(0) = f(t) - (0,0) \\
F(\tau_h(t)) &= F(t,1) = f(1)-f(t) = (0,1)- f(t)
\end{align*}
A little vector arithmetic gives us
$$\frac{1}{2} \bigl(F(\tau_v(t)) + F(\tau_h(t)\bigr) = (0,1/2)
$$
To say this in geometric language, for each $t \in [0,1]$, the point $(0,1/2)$ is the midpoint of the segment with endpoints $F(\tau_v(t))$ and $F(\tau_h(t))$. It follows that the path $F \circ \tau_v$ and path $F \circ \tau_h$ differ from each other by a $180^\circ$ rotation of the plane centered on the point $(0,1/2)$. In symbols, letting $\rho : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ denote that rotation, we have
$$\rho \circ (F \circ \tau_v)  = F \circ \tau_h
$$
Applying Fact 2 it follows that
$$W(F \circ \tau_h) = W(F \circ \tau_v)
$$

The path $F \circ \tau_v$ has initial and terminal endpoints 
$$F \circ \tau_v(0) = (0,0)
$$
$$F \circ \tau_v(1) = (0,1)
$$
and the point $(0,1/2)$ is the midpoint of the segment between those two endpoints. By applying Fact 1, the winding number of the path $F \circ \tau_v$ is a half-integer:
$$W(F \circ \tau_v) = n + \frac{1}{2} \quad\text{for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$}
$$
We therefore have
\begin{align*}
W(F \circ \tau_v) + W(F \circ \tau_h) &= W(F \circ \tau_v) + W(F \circ \tau_v) \\
&= 2 \cdot W(F \circ \tau_v) \\ 
&= 2n + 1
\end{align*}
which is an odd integer, and therefore nonzero.

Comment: Nice. I did not read the proof carefully yet, although a general proof for $n$i instead of $2$ would imply that winding numbers of simple loops are $1$. So, perhaps  the proof should also involve winding numbers somehow.

Comment: Looks very nice. There is another proof using a loop iof index $2$ around $0$ ( $\exp( 4 \pi f(t)) $ that cannot be injective  and producing $t_1$,, $t_2$, although it doesn't get  $t_1< t_2$. The same argument for any $n$ would produce inductively first some difference $\frac{k_1}{n}$, then $\frac{k_2}{n}$, till we reach $\frac{1}{n}$. But it uses the subtle thing that an injective loop has index $\pm 1$ (wr to $0$)... So maybe there is a direct proof along your approach.

Comment: When you say "$n$ instead of $2$", what exactly do you mean?  I'm guessing this refers to something in another answer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, if's $f(t_2)-f(t_1) = (0, 1/n)$.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is wrong, as pointed out by Wen. I won't delete it: maybe someone will find it useful to create a working counterexample**

I think this should work as a counterexample.
Take $a=0$, $b=7$. We will define $f$ piecewisely.
For $t\in[0,1]$,  $\ \ f(t)=(\frac{t}{2},0)  $;
for $t\in[1,2]$, $\ \ f(t)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{t-1}{4})$;
for $t\in[2,3]$, $\ \ f(t)=(\frac{1}{2}-(t-2),\frac{1}{4})$;
for $t\in[3,4]$  $\ \ f(t)=(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{8}(t-3))$;
for $t\in[4,5]$, $\ \ f(t)=(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(t-4),\frac{5}{8})$;
for $t\in[5,6]$, $\ \ f(t)=(1,\frac{5}{8}+\frac{3}{8}(t-5))$;
for $t\in[6,7]$, $\ \ f(t)=(1-(t-6),1)$.
Since it is possible that I made some mistake in the parametrization, the idea is the following:
Start from $(0,0)$; go along the x-axis to the point $(\frac{1}{2},0)$; go up to the point $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$; now "turn back" to the point $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$; now go up to the point $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{8})$. At this point you are above the points with y-coordinate $\frac{1}{2}$.  To add $\frac{3}{8}$ vertically, without having two points $t_1,t_2$ s.t. $f(t_1)-f(t_2)=(0,\frac{1}{2})$, you need to go back "beyond" $\frac{1}{2}$ in the x-direction, then you can reach the points with y-coordinate 1 "safely".

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but can you provide a picture? I don't quite get the 'go back beyond' 1/2

Comment: @Wen Is it clear now?

Comment: I believe that (1/2,1/8) an (1/2,5/8) both lie on your graph, so I don't think this works.

Comment: Well, I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the well-known concept of [Brouwer topological degree](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Brouwer_degree). Here is an brief intuitive idea (roughly speaking) of the construction of such tool..

Given a (at least) $C^2$ function $g\colon\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ (or, more generally, between two oriented manifolds of same dimension) and $y\in\mathbb R^n$ a regular value for $g$ such that $g^{-1}(y)$ is compact (therefore finite, by the inverse function theorem), one defines the Brouwer degree of $g$ at $y$ as the integer number
$$\deg(g,y) = \sum_{x\in g^{-1}(y)} {\rm sign}\det g'(x),$$
where $g'(x)$ is the jacobian matrix of $g$ at $x$ and ${\rm sign}\ t$ is $1$ for $t>0$ or $-1$ for $t<0$.

One can prove that this number is homotopy invariant, that is, if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic and $y$ is a regular value for both $f$ and $g$, then
$$\deg(f,y) = \deg(g,y).$$

Using Sard's theorem to define the degree of maps at critical points, we have that, given a $C^2$ function $h$, $\deg(h,\cdot)\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb Z$ is a continuous locally constant function.

Now, given a continuous function $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$, we can choose a smooth function $g$ "close enough from $f$" (using Weierstrass approximation theorem) and define the degree of $f$ at some value $y$ by
$$\deg(f,y) = \deg(g,y),$$
where the right side is already defined.

Briefly, the Brouwer degree can be thought as a map taking a continuous function $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ and some value $y\in\mathbb R^n$ and giving a integer number.

In addition, notice that if $\deg(f,y) \neq 0$ then the equation $f(x) = y$ has at least one solution.

---

Now we're ready to think about the problem.

Let ${\rm I} = [0,1]$ and $q=(0,1/2)$. Consider $\alpha\colon{\rm I}\to\mathbb R^2$ be a continuous function such that $\alpha(0) = (0,0)$ and $\alpha(1) = (0,1)$ and .

Let $\gamma\colon{\rm I}\to\mathbb R^2$ be the smooth function $$\gamma(t) = (\sin(\pi t), t).$$
Here is the plot of $\gamma$:
[image: plot of $\gamma$]

Define $F, G\colon {\rm I}^2\to\mathbb R^2$ (note the same dimension) by
$$F(x,y) = \alpha(x) - \alpha(y)$$ and $$G(x,y) = \gamma(x) - \gamma(y).$$

We have that $F$ and $G$ are homotopic since it assumes values on $\mathbb R^2$ (we can take the linear homotopy).
Therefore, $\deg(F,q) = \deg(G,q)$.

Let's calculate $\deg(G,q)$. First, we have to verify that $q$ is in fact a regular value for $G$ to then apply the degree formula. We are going to take a look at the set $G^{-1}(q)$.. with some straight forward calculations, we can see that
$$G(x,y) = q  \Leftrightarrow \left\{
\begin{matrix} x = k + 3/4 \\ y = k + 1/4 \end{matrix}\right. , k\in\mathbb Z$$
and $k=0$ gives the solution $(x,y)=(3/4,1/4)$, that lies in ${\rm I}^2$.
So $G^{-1}(q) = \{(3/4,1/4)\}$.

Note that
$$G'(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi\cos(\pi x) & -\pi\cos(\pi y) \\
1 & -1 \end{bmatrix},$$
thus
$$\det G'(x,y) = -\pi(\cos(\pi x) - \cos(\pi y))$$
and
$$\det G'(3/4,1/4) = \pi\sqrt{2} > 0.$$
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\deg(G,q) & = \sum_{(x,y)\in G^{-1}(q)} {\rm sign} \det G'(x,y) \\
& = {\rm sign} \det G'(3/4,1/4) \\
& = {\rm sign} \pi\sqrt{2} \\
& = 1.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Since $\deg(F,q) = \deg(G,q) = 1 \neq 0$, we conclude that there exists some $(x_0,y_0)\in{\rm I}^2$ such that $F(x_0,y_0) = q$, i.e.,
$$\alpha(x_0) - \alpha(y_0) = (0,1/2).$$

Comment: I  added in my answer an example of a curve without vertical chords of length $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @orangeskid I confess I didn't think a lot in the final of my answers (have a lot of calculations to do). So I'll remove it and be fine with the case when $T=1/2$. But it's bothering me that I can't change the $\alpha$ in my answer for the $f$ in your answer.. I'll think about where the argument do not work.

Comment: It is indeed a very puzzling problem. I am not even sure what the answer is. The example that I wrote it's an old classical example that I got from the paper provided in the link. Still thinking about it..

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a comment extending on an observation in [orangeskid's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2424954/415941) which is also discussed in his linked [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00871v1.pdf) (Proposition 4). It turns out that any (non-zero) vertical chord length can be avoided *except* $1/n$ with $n\in\Bbb N$. This means that any proof of the initial statement cannot use a general argument that fits any vertical chord length.

Check orangekid's answer to see how the folowing functions are used. Let $$f(x)=\sin(2\pi/\omega\cdot x)-x\sin(2\pi/\omega).$$

Note that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Consider $g(x):=f(x-\omega)$. We have

\begin{align}
g(x)&=\sin(2\pi/\omega\cdot x-2\pi)-(x-\omega)\sin(2\pi/\omega)\\
&=\sin(2\pi/\omega\cdot x)-x\sin(2\pi/\omega)+\omega\sin(2\pi/\omega)\\
&=f(x)+\omega\sin(2\pi/\omega).
\end{align}

Clearly $f$ and $g$ never intersect *except* when $\omega=1/n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. If they do not intersect then this is equivalent to say that the curve $(f(t),t)$ has no (vertical) chord of length $\omega$.

The paper shows (using the intermediate value theorem on the slope of chords) that OP's statement (generalized to chord lengths $1/n$) is indeed true for curves given via $(f(t),t)$ for some function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$ like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a curious theorem in Rolfsen's book "Knots and Links", and was reminded of this question.

> **Theorem B.15** (p. 16). Suppose $X$ is a path-connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$, and $C$ is a chord (that is, a line-segment) with endpoints in $X$. Suppose $0<\alpha<1$. Then among all chords with endpoints in X and parallel to $C$, there is either one of length $\alpha|C|$ (where $|C|$ is the length of the chord $C$) or one of length $(1-\alpha)|C|$.

Let $X$ be the curve in your question. Let $C$ be the chord from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$. Set $\alpha=1/2$. Theorem B.15 yields the existence of a chord with end points $x,y\in X$ and $x-y=(0,1/2)$.